# Discord bot not assigning users send messages permissions according [discord.py]

Tags: javascript, python, html, discord, bots

````
class Viewer(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(
        self,
        channel: discord.TextChannel,
        team_one: typing.List[discord.Member],
        team_two: typing.List[discord.Member],
    ) -> None:
        self.all_members = team_one + team_two
        self.team_one = team_one
        self.team_two = team_two

        self.channel = channel
        super().__init__()

    @discord.ui.button(label="Click me!", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary)
    async def caller(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button['Viewer']):
        arrangement1 = [":yellow_square:"] * 10
        arrangement2 = [":yellow_square:"] * 10
        arrangement3 = [
            ":wastebasket:",
            ":blue_square:",
            ":yellow_square:",
            ":yellow_square:",
            ":yellow_square:",
            ":yellow_square:",
            ":yellow_square:",
            ":yellow_square:",
            ":red_square:",
            ":yellow_square:",
        ]
        arrangement4 = [":yellow_square:"] * 10
        arrangement5 = [":yellow_square:"] * 10

        # Randomly choose a member from all_members list
        random_member = random.choice(self.all_members)

        # We can use overwrites here to change the permissions, doing that many API calls is not good
        overwrites = self.channel.overwrites
        overwrites[self.channel.guild.default_role] = discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=False,send_messages=False)
        overwrites[random_member] = discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True, send_messages=True)

        await self.channel.edit(overwrites=overwrites)
        await self.channel.send(f"{random_member.mention}, you have the ball!")

        # Check if the member is in team1 or team2
        if random_member in self.team_one:
            await self.channel.send(f"{random_member.mention} is in Team 1!")
        elif random_member in self.team_two:
            await self.channel.send(f"{random_member.mention} is in Team 2!")

        # Concatenate the strings with newline character "\n"
        joined_arrangements: typing.List[str] = [
            " ".join(arrangement) for arrangement in (arrangement1, arrangement2, arrangement3, arrangement4, arrangement5)
        ]
        messenger: str = '\n'.join(joined_arrangements)
        await interaction.response.send_message(messenger)


@client.command()
@commands.guild_only()
async def basketball(ctx: commands.Context[commands.Bot], upto: int, *members: discord.Member):
    assert ctx.guild
    assert isinstance(ctx.author, discord.Member)

    all_members: typing.List[discord.Member] = list(members)
    if ctx.author not in all_members:
        all_members.append(ctx.author)

    totalplayers = len(all_members)
    if totalplayers % 2 != 0:
        return await ctx.send("You cannot play as you do not have an even amount of players. Must be even.")

    mention_message = ' '.join(m.mention for m in all_members)
    await ctx.send(
        f"So {mention_message} want to play a basketball game. This game will be a {totalplayers//2}v{totalplayers//2}. Let's go somewhere a little more private. "
        "A channel will be created for you to play the game."
    )

    # Divide the teams only once, outside the loop
    team_one: typing.List[discord.Member] = random.sample(all_members, k=totalplayers // 2)
    team_two: typing.List[discord.Member] = [member for member in all_members if member not in team_one]

    # Create overwrites for this channel now that we can use to create it with
    overwrites: typing.Dict[typing.Union[discord.Member, discord.Role], discord.PermissionOverwrite] = {
        ctx.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=False),
    }

    for team_member in team_one + team_two:
        overwrites[team_member] = discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True)

    channel = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(
        f'{ctx.author.display_name}\'s Basketball Game',
        overwrites=overwrites,
        category=getattr(ctx.channel, 'category', None),
    )

    view = Viewer(channel, team_one, team_two)
    await channel.send(
        f"This is a basketball game to {upto}. Before I commence this game, I recommend you look at the rules.",
        view=view,
    )
    blue_team_message = "```\nBlue Team: " + ", ".join(str(member.display_name) for member in team_one) + "```"
    red_team_message = "```\nRed Team: " + ", ".join(str(member.display_name) for member in team_two) + "```"

    # Send the concatenated messages together
    await channel.send(f'{blue_team_message}\n{red_team_message}')
````

This is my entire code.

I have this piece of code,
that when I cickt the bttton
it disables the usesrs' permissions to send messages (settint them as FALSE)
apart from the random users, as in my `radnom_member` variable
This doesnt work though -
instead,
everyond send permissions remain as true
I have tried changing the oiverwrite metthod but all to no avail. Please help

Comment: Please edit the code into your question and don't use `pastebin` links.

Comment: my apologies dominic